# Архитектура настольного приложения

Tags: java, javafx, архитектура

Как можно создавать большое настольное приложение, чтобы не было большой зависимости между модулями, не приходилось делать сборку всего приложения из за изменения одного места в коде, к примеру на java fx. Вот на сервере можно использовать микросервисную архитектуру а как здесь быть.

Comment: В основном приложении делаете функционал `модулей` или `плагинов`. Устанавливаете для них некоторые требования - пакет и интерфейс для загрузки плагина. Делаете открытый функционал который позволит взаимодействовать плагину и основному приложению. Можно прикрутить продгрузку плагинов с сервера - `jar` файлы.

Comment: Можете использовать интерпретируемый язык программирования. Python, например.
Проблема со сборкой решена :)

Comment: @tsyklop А как можно сделать открытый функционал, они как то должны ведь общаться

Comment: Публичные классы, интерфейсы и т.д. К примеру что бы плагин был загружен Вы создаете некий `interface` и говорите что что бы плагин заработал нужно заимплементить Ваш интерфейс. По аналогии можно сделать но через абстрактный класс, тем самым давая уже как-то готовый функционал плагину.